# Update query for 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have this Query Below

```
string updateReq = "UPDATE Student SET Student.ID_Request = 
Request.ID_Request FROM Request where Student.St_Code=Request.St_Code   INNER JOIN  Request ON Student.ID_Request = 
Request.ID_Request";
```

but when i excute this i get this error :

> The objects "Request" and "Request" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

how can i solve this ?

i tried to select the records in the temp table but it doesn't work or maybe i do it wrong

```
string select = "SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM Student s where ID_Request IS NULL";

string updateReq = "UPDATE TempTable SET s.ID_Request = Request.ID_Request FROM Request where Student.St_Code=Request.St_Code  INNER JOIN  Request ON Student.ID_Request = Request.ID_Request";
```

when i excute these string i get the same error

Comment: mysql  or sql-server ?????  remove incompatible tags please

Comment: Tgere can only be one `from` clause in every statement (not including sub queries). Also, you are updating the students table but not referencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you intend this query:

```
UPDATE Student
    SET ID_Request = r.ID_Request
FROM Student s JOIN
     Request r
     ON s.St_Code = r.St_Code ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an Alias which is done using 'AS'

i.e.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS first
INNER JOIN table1 AS second ON second.col = first.col;
```